# Using CodeFormatter with K_UNKNOWN returns null

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-jdt

Trying this code with Eclipse Mars 4.5.1:

http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv%2Fguide%2Fjdt_api_codeformatter.htm

Relevant parts:

```java
Map options = DefaultCodeFormatterConstants.getEclipseDefaultSettings();
options.put(JavaCore.COMPILER_COMPLIANCE, JavaCore.VERSION_1_5);
options.put(JavaCore.COMPILER_CODEGEN_TARGET_PLATFORM, JavaCore.VERSION_1_5);
options.put(JavaCore.COMPILER_SOURCE, JavaCore.VERSION_1_5);

CodeFormatter codeFormatter = ToolFactory.createCodeFormatter(options);

String source = ...;

TextEdit edit = codeFormatter.format(
  CodeFormatter.K_COMPILATION_UNIT,
  source,
  0,
  source.length(),
  0,
  System.getProperty("line.separator")
);
```

It works fine like that, but when I change to `CodeFormatter.K_UNKNOWN` instead of `CodeFormatter.K_COMPILATION_UNIT`, it stops working - `edit` is `null`. I think this used to work fine with previous versions of Eclipse.

Since I don't know what type of string I'm getting at the point where I call format method, any way to use `K_UNKNOWN`?

Comment: 'I think this used to work fine ' - did you try to run the code with earlier versions?

Comment: Can you post the source? I did a quick test with 4.5.1 and `source = "Integer foo = new Integer( 12 );"` and `K_UNKNOWN` and this worked (i.e. returned TextEdit that removes spaces before/after brackets)